# Parallelizing comparisons between two dataframes with multiprocessing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, python-multiprocessing

I've got the following function that allows me to do some comparison between the rows of two dataframes (`data` and `ref`)and return the index of both rows if there's a match.

```
def get_gene(row):

    m = np.equal(row[0], ref.iloc[:,0].values) & np.greater_equal(row[2], ref.iloc[:,2].values) & np.less_equal(row[3], ref.iloc[:,3].values)

    return ref.index[m] if m.any() else None
```

Being a process that takes time (25min for 1.6M rows in `data` versus 20K rows in `ref`), I tried to speed things up by parallelizing the computation. As pandas doesn't support multiprocessing natively, I used this piece of code that I found on SO and it worked ok with my function `get_gene`.

```
def _apply_df(args):
    df, func, kwargs = args
    return df.apply(func, **kwargs)


def apply_by_multiprocessing(df, func, **kwargs):

    workers = kwargs.pop('workers')
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=workers)

    result = pool.map(_apply_df, [(d, func, kwargs) for d in np.array_split(df, workers)])

    pool.close()

    df = pd.concat(list(result))

    return df
```

It allowed me to go down to 9min of computation. But, if I understood correctly, this code just breaks down my dataframe `data` in 4 pieces and send each one to each core of the CPU. Hence, each core ends up doing a comparisons between 400K rows (from `data` split in 4) versus 20K rows (`ref`).

What I would actually want to do is to split both dataframes based on a value in one of their column so that I only compute comparisons between dataframes of the same 'group':

- `data.get_group(['a'])` versus `ref.get_group(['a'])`
- `data.get_group(['b'])` versus `ref.get_group(['b'])`
- `data.get_group(['c'])` versus `ref.get_group(['c'])`
- etc...

which would reduce the amount of computation to do. Each row in `data` would only be able to be matched against ~3K rows in `ref`, instead of all 20K rows.

Therefore, I tried to modify the code above but I couldn't manage to make it work.

```
def apply_get_gene(df, func, **kwargs):

    reference = pd.read_csv('genomic_positions.csv', index_col=0)
    reference = reference.groupby(['Chr'])

    df = df.groupby(['Chr'])
    chromosome = df.groups.keys()



    workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=workers)


    args_list = [(df.get_group(chrom), func, kwargs, reference.get_group(chrom)) for chrom in chromosome]

    results = pool.map(_apply_df, args_list)

    pool.close()                                                          
    pool.join()                                                           

    return pd.concat(results)


def _apply_df(args):

    df, func, kwarg1, kwarg2 = args

    return df.apply(func, **kwargs)


def get_gene(row, ref):

    m = np.equal(row[0], ref.iloc[:,0].values) & np.greater_equal(row[2], ref.iloc[:,2].values) & np.less_equal(row[3], ref.iloc[:,3].values)

    return ref.index[m] if m.any() else None
```

I'm pretty sure it has to do with the way of how `*args` and `**kwargs` are passed trough the different functions (because in this case I have to take into account that I want to pass my splitted `ref` dataframe with the splitted `data` dataframe..). 
I think the problem lies within the function `_apply_df`. I thought I understood what it really does but the line `df, func, kwargs = args` is still bugging me and I think I failed to modify it correctly..

All advices are appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [`starmap()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap):

> starmap(func, iterable[, chunksize])
>   Like map() except that the elements of the iterable are expected to be iterables that are unpacked as arguments.
>
> Hence an iterable of [(1,2), (3, 4)] results in [func(1,2), func(3,4)].

Which seems to be exactly what you need.

Comment: so that mean I could get rid of the `_apply_df` function who's just here because `map()` just takes one argument unlike apply ? I'm gonna take a look at that, thanks !

Comment: Indeed, let me know if it doesn't work for some reason!

Comment: Maybe I missed something but I'm not sure `starmap()` behave like `apply()`. The good thing with the `_apply_df` function was that it allowed to return something like `df.apply(func, axis=1)` and I'm not sure I can get that with `starmap()` ..

Comment: I came up with something that works. Please see my post if needed. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

I post the answer I came up with for readers who might stumble upon this post:

As noted by @Michele Tonutti, I just had to use `starmap()` and do a bit of tweaking here and there. The tradeoff is that it applies only my custom function `get_gene` with the setting `axis=1` but there's probably a way to make it more flexible if needed.

```
def Detect_gene(data):

    reference = pd.read_csv('genomic_positions.csv', index_col=0)
    ref = reference.groupby(['Chr'])

    df = data.groupby(['Chr'])
    chromosome = df.groups.keys()

    workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=workers)


    args = [(df.get_group(chrom), ref.get_group(chrom)) 
            for chrom in chromosome]

    results = pool.starmap(apply_get_gene, args)

    pool.close()                                                          
    pool.join()                                                           

    return pd.concat(results)


def apply_get_gene(df, a):

    return df.apply(get_gene, axis=1, ref=a)


def get_gene(row, ref):

    m = np.equal(row[0], ref.iloc[:,0].values) & np.greater_equal(row[2], ref.iloc[:,2].values) & np.less_equal(row[3], ref.iloc[:,3].values)

    return ref.index[m] if m.any() else None
```

It now takes ~5min instead of ~9min with the former version of the code and ~25min without multiprocessing.